# GASで複数シートを選択した状態で、そのシート情報を取得したい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

タイトルの通りなのですが、SpreadSheetの操作でシートを複数選択した状態で、スクリプトを実行して、GAS上で、そのシートの選択枚数と選択したシートの名前などが取得したいです。

単純そうなのですが、ネット上で調べても、検索ワードのせいなのか、あるいは実現することが不可能なのか、実現しているサイトを見つけることができませんでした。

ご存知でしたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドキュメントを見る限り、 **複数の** 選択されたシートの情報を取得するようなメソッドは存在しないようです。(あるのは **アクティブなシート** の情報を取得するメソッド)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=ja